# Passing property from reflection into expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection, lambda

I want to loop through my model properties using reflection, and then pass them into a method expecting my property as en expression.

For example, given this model:

```
public class UserModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And this validator class:

```
public class UserValidator : ValidatorBase<UserModel>
{
    public UserValidator()
    {
        this.RuleFor(m => m.Username);
    }
}
```

And my ValidatorBase class:

```
public class ValidatorBase<T>
{
    public ValidatorBase()
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in 
                     this.GetType().BaseType
                         .GetGenericArguments()[0]
                         .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Insance))
        {
            this.RuleFor(m => property); //This line is incorrect!!
        }
    }

    public void RuleFor<TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        //Do some stuff here
    }
}
```

The issue is with the `ValidatorBase()` constructor -- given that I have the `PropertyInfo` for the property I need, what should I pass into as the `expression` parameter in the `RuleFor` method, such that it works just like the line in `UserValidator()` constructor?

Or, should I be using something else besides `PropertyInfo` to get this to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect you want:

```
ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
Expression propertyAccess = Expression.Property(parameter, property);
// Make it easier to call RuleFor without knowing TProperty
dynamic lambda = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);
RuleFor(lambda);
```

Basically it's a matter of building an expression tree for the property... dynamic typing from C# 4 is just used to make it easier to call `RuleFor` without explicitly doing that via reflection. You *could* do it, of course - but you'd need to fetch the `RuleFor` method, then call `MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod` with the property type, then invoke the method.